# Number and type of slashes in path in command prompt

Tags: java

This is kind of a ridiculous question but I am stucked with it and I need some help.
I am trying to install an open source software in my windows 8 system using command prompt. Everything is set correctly but when I type the final java command, to run the software, I get a series of exceptions. 
I am sure that the problem is related with some slashes in the path. I know that the type and number of slashes is important and sometimes java requires this. 
So I am not sure if I can get an answer about such a specific question here but I give it a try. This is the path I run in one line:

```
 C:\Kuwaiba7\service>java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/C:/Kuwaiba7/service/lib/PersistenceAbstractionAPI.jar file:/C:/Kuwaiba7/Service/lib/PersistenceServiceRemoteInterfaces.jar" -jar PersistenceService.jar
```

I double/tripled checked the paths and tried different variations with the slashes but nothing gives me the expected result.
I get the following exceptions:

```
     java.rmi.serverException
     java.rmi.unmarshalException
     java.lang.classNotFoundException
```

This is the format of the path they suggest in their manual but doesn't seem to work either: [image]

Thanks 
Dimitris

Comment: " I get a series of exceptions." --> *which* series of exceptions. Be detailed and specific please. Also, your screenshot clearly shows the the advice is to use single *forward* slashes, yet in the path you run you are using *backward* slashes. Change the slashes - even if that doesn't work either, it at least clearly shows that you have followed the obvious advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I post the answer here. Afterall the slashes were correct the way I had them. Although sometimes in Java the number and the type of the slashes counts that wasn't the case here. 
What I did before was that I was starting the rmiregistry and then running the PersistenceService. That didn't work. 
Then I tried to set the Classpath (from the directory where the PersistenceService.jar is located in my PC). After start the rmiregistry.exe (from the Java directory) and finally run the persistence service as shown above.
That made it work!